# ec2 ubuntu name or service unknown error when running jupyter notebook

Tags: python, python-3.x, ubuntu, amazon-ec2, jupyter-notebook

I am using ec2 with ubuntu 18 machine, and wish to install jupyter notebook, I followed [this](https://medium.com/@alexjsanchez/python-3-notebooks-on-aws-ec2-in-15-mostly-easy-steps-2ec5e662c6c6) tutorial and keep getting this error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "/home/ubuntu/.local/bin/jupyter-notebook", line 11, in 
>       sys.exit(main())   File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/jupyter_core/application.py",
>   line 266, in launch_instance
>       return super(JupyterApp, cls).launch_instance(argv=argv, **kwargs)   File
>   "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/traitlets/config/application.py",
>   line 657, in launch_instance
>       app.initialize(argv)   File "",
>   line 2, in initialize   File
>   "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/traitlets/config/application.py",
>   line 87, in catch_config_error
>       return method(app, *args, **kwargs)   File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/notebook/notebookapp.py",
>   line 1628, in initialize
>       self.init_webapp()   File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/notebook/notebookapp.py",
>   line 1378, in init_webapp
>       self.jinja_environment_options,   File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/notebook/notebookapp.py",
>   line 159, in **init**
>       default_url, settings_overrides, jinja_env_options)   File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/notebook/notebookapp.py",
>   line 252, in init_settings
>       allow_remote_access=jupyter_app.allow_remote_access,   File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/traitlets/traitlets.py",
>   line 556, in **get**
>       return self.get(obj, cls)   File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/traitlets/traitlets.py",
>   line 535, in get
>       value = self._validate(obj, dynamic_default())   File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/notebook/notebookapp.py",
>   line 867, in _default_allow_remote
>       for info in socket.getaddrinfo(self.ip, self.port, 0, socket.SOCK_STREAM):   File "/usr/lib/python3.6/socket.py", line 745,
>   in getaddrinfo
>       for res in _socket.getaddrinfo(host, port, family, type, proto, flags): socket.gaierror: [Errno -2] Name or service not known

Ports 22 and 8888 are open to my ip

What am i doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works when I run it the same way with a conda instead of python